# Disable item quantity and shopping cart in paypal

Tags: paypal

My site is going to use paypal to pay for items.

I only want one item to be able to be bought at a time, and only 1 quantity of that item.

I've been looking around in paypal's options and haven't found anything yet.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use cookies, sessions or database entries to track who's bought what then work from there.

Comment: I don't think that will stop users from buying multiple items and mass quantity the initial buy though.

Comment: Other than that, I'm sure you can select max quantity when creating the paypal button it's self.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting to sell one item at a time, you probably don't need shopping cart functionality - the 'Buy Now' button would be more suitable for this purpose as 'one item at a time' is default behavior. Additionally, if you are looking to enforce a 'one purchase per customer', then as Gtoxic mentioned - cookies would probably be the best bet with the limited info provided.

Comment: Yep, Daniel is right. Checkout this link: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/website-payments-standard/disable-shopping-cart-quantity